# Laravel WhereNotIn only one number

Tags: mysql, laravel

Here is code:

```
$all = "32,34,24,28,31";
 $show_app = DB::table('apartments')
->whereNotIn('id', [$all])
->get();
```

I don't know why variable $all not working.
When is listed only hide first apartment "32". Rest apartment list anyway. But if i copy all numbers in whereNotIn then is working??? 
I need this variable @all!
I have all variable in my table. I try with `->toSql()` and show only one `"?"` instead of five `"?, ?, ?, ?, ?"`

Comment: `$all = [32,34,24,28,31];` And `->whereNotIn('id', $all)`

Answer (score 1):

I am not a laravel user, but in your all variable, why not directly assign the array instead of saving as string?

Example:
Instead of:

```
$all = "32,34,24,28,31";
```

why not?

```
$all = [32,34,24,28,31];
```

Then use the $all variable like this:.

```
 $show_app =    DB::table('apartments') ->whereNotIn('id', $all) ->get();
```

Comment: It's working but when i used data from query
$result="";
foreach($prikaz_bookinga as $prikaz_booking) :  
$result.=$prikaz_booking->id.','; 
endforeach ;
$notIn=rtrim($result, ',');
$all="[".$notIn."]";
echo $all;
show: [32,34,24,28,31,32]  what i need
but when i used in
 ->whereNotIn('id', $all)
then show error
ErrorException in Builder.php line 775: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

i found my problem:
I must use explode

```
$result="";
foreach($prikaz_bookinga as $prikaz_booking) :  
$result.=$prikaz_booking->id.','; 
endforeach ;
$all=rtrim($result, ',');
```

Then in query add this.

```
 ->whereNotIn('id', explode(',', $all))
```

Now i go to drink beer. Work on this 8 days.